# Turning a for(;;) loop into a foreach

Tags: c#, .net, loops, for-loop

So I've been trying to turn this codes for into a for each, but I keep running into problems, and I'm not all that sure how to do it, the only thing I've done that will work is a small code but it repeats several times, I'm still really new to C# and using for() so I'm not really understanding what to do. Sorry for being so new to this, and I appreciate all the help I can get!

```
double[] numbers = new double[9.7, 2.2, 4.3, 1.7, 5.6, 3.6, 4.5, 1.3, 4.6, 3.0];

static double ComputeSum(double[] array)
{
    double sum = 0;
    int intCounter;

    for (intCounter = 0; intCounter < array.Length; intCounter++)
    {
        sum += array[intCounter];
    }
    return sum;
}

static double ComputeAverage(double[] array)
{
    return ComputeSum(array) / array.Length;
}
```

Comment: If you use the IEnumerable<T>.Sum() extension you don't need a for loop (or foreach) because the loop is already inside the Sum method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got your specific question answered, but not the more general question of "how do I turn a `for` loop into a `foreach`?

Let's look at your loop, with some better naming. (Don't name things according to their type in C#. Name things according to their meaning.)

```
        for (index = 0; index< array.Length; index++)
        {
            sum += array[index];
        }
```

The most important thing is that you understand the *idea* that this loop represents. A surface level reading is "for every valid index in this array, obtain the element value associated with that index and add it to the sum".  But we can make that a bit more abstract. We could also say that the loop means "for every element in the collection, add it to the sum".

That is the key difference between the `for` loop and the `foreach` loop. The `for` loop concentrates on the *index*, and you fetch the value via the index. The `foreach` loop concentrates on the *value itself*, and doesn't consider the index at all.

Knowing that we can now see how to translate a `for` into a `foreach`.  First locate the bit that is the value, and make a variable for it:

```
        for (index = 0; index < array.Length; index++)
        {
            var item = array[index];
            sum += item;
        }
```

Now we see that the loop body can be expressed almost entirely in terms of an operation on the item, not on the index.  We then translate that into a `foreach`:

```
        foreach (var item in array)
        {
            sum += item;
        }
```

Everything dealing with the index gets deleted. If you find you cannot delete everything dealing with the index, then you probably should not be using a `foreach`.

Answer (score 3):

Since `foreach` loop presents elements of the collection one-by-one to your code, all you need to do is

```
foreach (double num in Numbers)
{
    sump += num;
}
Console.WriteLine("{0}", sump);
```

You could also use `Sum` extension method to eliminate loop constructs altogether:

```
var sump = Numbers.Sum(); // <<== The loop is hidden inside the Sum() method
Console.WriteLine("{0}", sump);
```